# Android соединение с интернетом

Tags: android

Нужно постоянно подключаться к серверу и принимать информацию с него, примерно раз в секунду. Можно ли сделать наоборот, не к серверу подключаться, а чтобы сервер подключался к android'у?

Comment: теоретически можно

Comment: Теоретически? А практически каким образом?

Comment: Чтобы сервер подключался к android , нужно как минимум , чтобы у телефона был статический IP (если это всё будет происходить в интернете)

Answer (score 1):

Если вам нужно лишь получать какие-то данные от бэкэнда, то, вместо периодического опроса сервера клиентом на наличие изменений, можете использовать [GCM](http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/index.html).

Comment: как один из вариантов подойдет, но это не самый лучший. GCM - очень ненадежная штука, даже гугл не гарантирует доставку сообщений. подробно можно здесь почитать http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/adv.html#lifetime

Comment: У вас есть вариант лучше? И да, в чём же ненадёжность GCM'а? Гугл как раз гарантирует доставку сообщения, укладывающегося в пределы bucket limit (для этого предусмотрен collapse key) и message TTL. 

Причины, по которым сообщение может быть не доставлено: превышен bucket limit (и не использовался collapse key, или же превышен collapse keys limit), превышен message TTL (который по умолчанию составляет аж 4 недели), или же registration id более не валиден. Во всех остальных случаях сообщение будет доставлено.